# Axon : While Enabling JPA repository giving errorTokenEntry is not mapped

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, axon

In order to use multiple database in Springboot application having Axon framework.
I used @EnableJpaRepositories after which I started getting following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TokenEntry is not mapped [SELECT te.segment FROM TokenEntry te WHERE te.processorName = :processorName ORDER BY te.segment ASC]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:816)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.fetchSegments(JpaTokenStore.java:194)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1195)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TokenEntry is not mapped [SELECT te.segment FROM TokenEntry te WHERE te.processorName = :processorName ORDER BY te.segment ASC]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TokenEntry is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Following is the way I enabled JPA repositories

```
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.mypackage","org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "postgresTransactionManager")}
)
public class PostgresConfiguration {
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of code? For example your `DataSource` configuration, if you are using any migration script (eg: `Flyway`) and your `application.yml` as well, if possible.

Comment: @LucasCampos This is how I configured one of the database `@Data
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.mypackage",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "postgresTransactionManager"
)
public class PostgresConfiguration {

   @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource pGDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       //all creds and properties goes here 
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I'd assume this to work out of the box really.
Are you using Spring Boot by any chance @tijo? To be honest I am assuming not, but it does give me a suggestion.

Axon Framework uses the `@RegisterDefaultEntities` annotation to register the required entities automatically for you when you're using the `axon-springboot-starter`. You can see this being done on the [`JpaAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/axonframework/springboot/autoconfig/JpaAutoConfiguration.java) class.

What's being done there is the following:

```java
@RegisterDefaultEntities(packages = {
        "org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore",
        "org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa"
})
public class JpaAutoConfiguration { ... }
```

Would you mind checking whether that works? Main difference I see in your config is that you're only using the `"org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstorejpa"` base package.

Let us know whether this does the trick!